# Where should I connect the green ground wire in main panel next to meter?

Tags: electrical-panel

I am wondering what would be the correct location to connect the unconnected green ground wire in main panel next to meter. The detached garage has it's own ground rod. It is being fed by the double pole 50 amp breaker in main panel next to meter. I attached photos. The bare aluminum cable in main connects to ground bus bar in breaker box located inside house. The ground rod under meter connects to inside meter box only.
The hanging #6 green wire and 3 other black #6 wires run 60ft underground in conduit to detached garage sub panel. Two black #6 are on each pole of double 50 amp breaker and other black #6 is on neutral bar of main box next to meter.

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: One of the best styled subpanel questions I've seen in an age.  Did the research, shows work, asks one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fit a ground bar to the main panel, land it there

While, since you're working in a main panel here, you could commingle neutrals and grounds by landing your new ground wire on one of the neutral bars, it's cleaner to avoid that altogether and install a separate ground bar into the main panel instead for the ground wires.  Since you have a Square-D main panel, the correct part for your situation is a PK12GTA or PK15GTA -- you should be able to find it at a local electrical supply house or order it online for about $10.  Simply mount it to the main panel's cabinet in the holes provided, with the meter pulled for the duration (there should be a set top left or top right -- if not, the install instructions give guidance on drilling a set of mounting holes), then attach the ground wire to the newly fitted ground bar.  Once that's done, have the electric company turn the power back on, and enjoy your new subpanel!

(The previous installer committed a bit of a no-no by using a black wire for a neutral and phase-taping it instead of using a white wire, but that can be rectified down the road if it ever becomes an issue.  I would suggest phase taping it white at this point, at a minimum, to avoid needless confusion due to the previous installer's non-standard phase-taping scheme.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The tape was my fault. I used it to help me identify wires after pulling through conduit. They didn't have #6 white in stock. So I can fix by wrapping neutral wire with white electrical tape, correct?

Comment: So is removing the meter for safety or to connect ground bar to the copper ground in meter box with a copper ground wire? After installing ground bar and connecting green wire will any other wires need to be connected to ground bar?

Comment: Yeah, in conduit you're not allowed to phase-mark wires to change their purpose among hot/neutral/ground, unless they are #4 or larger.  You can,t even mark a white wire hot in a switch loop.  A good reason to go #4Al in an application like this.

Comment: Could the OP remove one of the ground bars from the subpanel and install it in the main panel? There is no need for two ground bars in the subpanel, right?

Comment: @MKlein the white electrical tape isn't Code, but it's an improvement over the current situation.  Having the power company cut power (since you have a smart meter, they likely can do this from the comfort of their office) is for safety's sake since you're working in the main panel, especially since your panel lacks service barriers over the incoming hot wires.

Comment: @JimStewart -- he could, but it comes at a cost in neatness if you will

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, won't switching off that main breaker depower the busses to the lugs which go to the inside panel (and to the garage subpanel)? So the inside panel with all the branch circuit breakers is technically a subpanel, right? Presumably the inside panel will not have a main disconnection breaker, or will it? I have seen a panel like this (done by a really high quality builder in Gulfport MS) with no main disconnection breaker in the *inside* panel. I was stunned. Most people expect to be able to turn off their power with one flip at what they would consider the main panel.

Comment: @JimStewart -- the inside panel is a subpanel in this case, yes.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, So neutral and ground should not be bonded in the inside panel, right?

Comment: @JimStewart -- correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87461/discussion-between-jim-stewart-and-threephaseeel).

Comment: His neutral and ground are already commingled.  (In my area, it's required by code to comingle at the meter.)  Unless I'm missing something, all he has to do is connect his green to the neutral bar on the left and he's as well connected as everything else in his house without adding a new grounding spike.

Comment: @JBH -- he can commingle N and G in the main if he wishes -- I simply favor not doing that as I consider commingled N/G a sign of a not-so-neat-and-tidy installation.  Also, your area forbids separate-but-bonded N/G bars in main panels?!

Comment: Again, thanks for all the great information. I am attaching all updated photos plus a look at the panel inside the house. Green wire is now connected to the Square D ground bar attached with two screws to main panel. So if lightning strikes is main panel ground to meter via the metal conduit connecting them together?

Comment: @MKlein -- that metal conduit will bond the meter pan and main panel together, yes, provided the proper bonding-type locknuts were used.  BTW: we show our thanks here by upvoting and/or accepting answers that help us out :)